# Powershell: Updating hotkeys for shortcuts via powershell does not work

Tags: windows, powershell, shortcut-file

On my windows desktop I have a folder called Links with one file: Firefox.lnk

I manually set a hotkey "CTRL+SHIFT+F" for this shortcut and everything worked as expected.

But after a reboot my hotkey "CTRL+SHIFT+F" does not work any more.

Manually setting the hotkey back to "" and then back to "CTRL+SHIFT+F" makes it work again.

But planning to put more files into this folder - the manual solution was not an option - so my plan was to set all shortcut hotkeys to an empty string via a powershell script and then run the following script to set all hotekeys to "CTRL+SHIFT+FirstletterOfShortcutFileName".

The first script sets the hotkey back to "" (manual check) and after running the following script the hotkey of the firefox shortcut was set to "CTRL+SHIFT+F". But unfortunately the hotkey does not work.
How can I make it work?

```
$lnkfiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Links\" -Filter *.lnk
foreach($lnkfile in $lnkfiles){
    $sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
    $targetPath = $sh.CreateShortcut($lnkfile.FullName)
    $fileName = Split-Path $targetPath.FullName -leaf
    $firstLetter = $fileName[0]
    $targetPath.HotKey = "CTRL+SHIFT+" + $firstLetter
    $targetPath.Save()
}
```

Comment: I'd say that `.HotKey` works only for shortcuts on your desktop (_does not_ in a subfolder of the desktop).

Comment: The hotkeys work when added manually - even in a subfolder.

Comment: Do the _manually added_ hotkeys _in a subfolder_ work even after computer restart?

Comment: Nope – just moved the shortcut to the desktop and after a restart the hotkey is not working

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things wrong with your code, mainly you are setting the `HotKey` property on the target path instead of the link, and also you are using the `Save()` method on the target path instead of the link.

This should do what you want:

```
$rootPath = 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\Links'
$wshShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Filter *.lnk | ForEach-Object {
    $shortcut        = $wshShell.CreateShortcut($_.FullName)
    $target          = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($shortcut.TargetPath)
    $shortcut.HotKey = 'CTRL+SHIFT+{0}' -f $target.Substring(0,1).ToUpperInvariant()
    $shortcut.Save()
    # cleanup this shortcut COM object after use
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shortcut) | Out-Null
}

# clean up the WScript.Shell COM object after use
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wshShell) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

<sup>P.S. I wouldn't do a combination of CTRL+SHIFT+.. because too many default hotkeys in Windows use that. Perhaps better do something with CTRL+ALT+..</sup>

Comment: Your P.S. is the solution - now everything works! Manually I always typed CTRL+ALT but in my code it was CTRL+SHIFT - soooooo stupid